# How can I use a foreach in Powershell on an array

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am querying a MySQL database and getting the only 2 columns I need alert_limit and customer_email. I am planning to be able to select each email individually with the alert limit value and use them as variables into a SMTP param.

Update: to answer Luuk's question I am using the SimplySql Powershell module. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SimplySql/1.6.2

```
$query = Invoke-SqlQuery -query "SELECT distinct alerts.* FROM alerts, joblog Where alert_enabled=1 and joblog.customer_id=alerts.customer_id AND alert_limit;"  | select "alert_limit", "customer_email"
```

The result is:

```
alert_limit customer_email             
----------- --------------             
        150 user1@email1.com 
      12000 user2@email2.com 
      10000 user3@email3.com
```

I am trying to send an individual email to each customer_email with their alert)limit in the body as below:

```
$Parameters = @{
    ToAddress   = '$customer_email'
    FromAddress = "notifications@system.com"
    Subject     = "Credits"
    Body        = "your credits are bellow" '$alert_limit'
```

but I struggle to select individual entries. thanks

Comment: Did you read the help from Microsoft about [ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.2) ?

Comment: BTW: Where did you find "Invoke-SqlQuery" which can use MySQL  (can you add that info to your question using [edit]?)

Comment: As for `"your credits are bellow" '$alert_limit'`: you need `+` to concatenate strings, and `'...'` strings are _verbatim_ strings, so your variable reference won't be expanded. See [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules)

Comment: My struggle is to select them as variables that can be parsed to the SMTP params. I imagine is quite trivial, but unfortunately, I have not done it before.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it.

```
 ForEach($customer in $query) {

   $alert_limit= $customer.alert_limit
   $customer_email =  $customer.customer_email

$Parameters = @{
    ToAddress   ="$customer_email"
    FromAddress = "notifications@system.com"
    Subject     = "Credits"
    Body        = "your credits are below<br> $alert_limit"

}
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work. You need to replace `'$customer_email'` with `"$customer_email"` and `"your credits are bellow" '$alert_limit'` with `"your credits are bellow<br>$alert_limit"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You are right. My answer has been corrected.